# Bot function after NoFollow rule

Tags: bots, noindex

I was just wondering what the function of googlebot or any other search engine spider/bot was after you use the no follow rule in a meta tag.  Presumably the bot is on your site and gets to a page through link redirection, etc but if the linked page includes the code `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">`, where does the bot go after that? Does it go back to the previous page or does it do some other function?  Hope this doesn't sound like a stupid question but I was just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually, a web crawler does not visit links found on a given webpage directly when he encounters them, instead these links are added to a waiting list, when the spider finish loading the current page, he just look up into this list and pop another url from there, the new link is not necessary from the last fetched page, it can be from the previous page or even another website ( depending how the list is organized ).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me - Your answer is very much appreciated and has helped alot